# AFNetworking leaks

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, afnetworking

'm loading many images using
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest

However the images are never being released, even when the objects using them are.
Is there a way to force these objects to go away?

I believe AFNetworking is caching these objects is there a way to disable that option?

Comment: So are these images in a table view? Can you give more information where these images are. I use setimagewithurlrequest in a table view and afnetworking works fine managing memory by removing the images that are not on screen